Should I have tried for slam in the following situation, and if so, did I do so in the right way?
With only them vulnerable at matchpoints, my (new) partner dealt and opened one club. After a pass by opponent, I bid one diamond with the following: (s) 7 (h) KQ (d) KT98543 (c) KT3.
Partner bid 2NT (balanced, 18-19). I decided to try for slam with 4NT (quantitative). Counting my 11, we had only 29 high card points between us, but with seven diamonds, I added two points each for the two long diamonds (above 5), bringing the total to 33. (A pair needs about 31 to be even money for a small slam.)
Partner took my bid for Blackwood, and bid 5 clubs, showing four aces.  I took that as a sign off bid at 5 clubs, with one major suit unguarded, and figured that with three card support, clubs would be a good place. But I now believe that I should have continued in diamonds, since I had seven, and partner at least two.
We went down at five clubs (partner had a 4-4-2-3 distribution with all four aces and the queen of spades). We would have made six diamonds or six no trump.
Was I right to try for slam with my holding? Did I do so the right way or did partner reasonably take my 4NT bid for something other than quantitative? And should I at least have "pulled" five clubs to five diamonds?

4N is quantitative if you've agreed with partner it's quantitative and Blackwood if you've agreed with partner it's Blackwood.  If you haven't discussed this with partner, discuss it.  If you're not in a situation where it can be discussed, then don't care if it goes wrong, and don't ask what it 'should' be, because there is no 'should' here.

That said, I don't know of a single decent player who plays ordinary Blackwood in any situation (maybe except 1suit-immediate4N), and I don't know a single decent partnership that doesn't have some artificial bids for responder after 1X-1Y-2N to enable both finding the right game and starting slam exploration at a lower level.

Yes, the playing strength is sufficient to investigate slam - but with a new and questionable partner you have no methods for a proper investigation. So what are your odds if you just wing it?
Partner has 2/3 of the remaining points, and your main concern is that you are missing 2 aces: The odds are (close enough for bidding decisions, though possibly not for play decisions):

(⅔)4 = 16/81 = ~20% that Partner has all four of them; and
4 * (⅔)3 * ⅓ = 32/81 = ~40% that Partner has three of them.

That adds to ~60% - and you should just bid 6 diamonds. Defenders can make an inaccurate assumption from your bidding; or even just err in their analysis. These perhaps increase your odds a bit more.
Yes, the above ignores space considerations in Partner's hand - but it's easier to place 4 points in his hand with an ace than it is with 2 or 3 other cards. That is a significant counterbalance to the space considerations; he has to have his 18-19 points somewhere, and you're already accounting for 3 of the 4 kings that are the next easiest way to place a 4 point combination in his hand.
The wild card hand - yours - will be hidden; so if you still need to pull a fast one on the defense, do it in tempo on trick 1 or 2.

A few things to say here.
First, don't assume that partner has failed to understand your bid. If you think that 4NT is quantitative, how could partner sign off in 5C? That doesn't really make sense. They have no idea what you have; 5C may be a much worse contract than 4NT. It's good to have agreements in these situations, but with a pickup partner you may not. In any case, 5C has to be a forward-going bid that's looking to pick the best slam. If partner stretched to bid 2NT with long clubs (not a good idea), they just have to swallow the bad score and pass 4NT, because at this point finding the best slam is the focus. But in any case, it is sensible to be able to respond to quantitative with a forward-going bid, and less sensible to be able to respond with a signoff.
Second, it was correct to look for slam here. I disagree that 4NT is the right approach. Why do you think that asking partner whether they have a min or a max is the right way to determine whether you have slam?
The question you need to answer is this: Do you have a diamond fit and 3 out of the 4 aces? If partner holds Axxx Axx Axxx Ax then you are making seven (partner only has 16!). If, on the other hand, partner holds AKQJ JTxx Qx AQJ then you are probably going down in a small slam (partner has 20!). It's about degree of fit, and controls. Standard agreements can't handle it. Gerber could answer part of this: if partner has 3 or 4 aces, you're probably making a small slam. Without tools to find out more, probably you should just jump to 6D. It may be right, or opponents may make the wrong lead.

Agree with all - you should try.
However, 4NT isn't the try, even if you're both on the same page that it's quantitative.
You can't add length points to your HCP to make a quantitative slam try; it needs 33 Miltons.  Because otherwise you can be off two aces.  The game doesn't care if you can take 16 of the last 11 tricks if you're off two aces that get cashed first. (yes, even with 33, you can be off AK suited.  Very very rare.)
You are correct that 31 with two balanced hands is slightly better than 50% to make slam; but only if you're not off two quicks.  The way to find that out is not "pretend I have more HCP than I have; the two aces will magically compress into one".
Without agreements, I like bash-and-hope; at least it doesn't (until dummy comes down, in 6NT - which is why 6♦ was the suggestion, and is the right bash) flag that there could be two aces missing, unless they're both in leader's hand (or that they cash! You didn't ace-ask, why?  Because you have a void!)
Definitely agreements help; in this auction, I play "the only non-game-forcing call is pass" with almost everybody (including, without discussion, pickup partners in my city).  I have an alternative to 6♦ - 3♦.  100% forcing, clearly a slam try (else why not just 3NT? or in very odd cases 5♦?), partner should be able to evaluate.  And I've pointed out the focus ("tricks are coming from running my suit") and we have the entire 3 and 4 level to work out the rest.
Others, as shown in their answers, have other methods, but mine are simple.  I understand that in your circle, you don't have that guarantee (I agree, +190 is an embarrassing score!) - but you should.
But even without those agreements, there's an evil one that might just work.  As ruds says, 4 aces and out should be golden; 4♣ is Gerber (for almost everybody), no?  (Which is why 4NT can be quantitative)

Yes, there are those who think that 4NT is blackwood (of some sort), and 4♣ is Gerber, and never clue into the fact that they have two bids for one situation and zero for another.
Yes, I would be very happy if nobody asked me to play Gerber ever again (several of my partnerships have "Gerber is baby food" on the card).
Yes, even with this hand, Gerber is wrong (what if you get 3?  Do you have a call that says "slam is on if your hand is good for diamonds" and a call that says "don't you dare go on, we're off two aces" if partner showed only two?), and there are clearly better ways to bid this (which is why I would be happy to never play it again - it's too easy a crutch for even experienced partners to jump for).

but it's still better than "go on 19, don't on 18, I don't care how many aces you have, because we won't be off two if you go."
Having said that, it is clear that 5♣ is not to play and must be "partner thought I was ace-asking".  There is just no hand that was willing to play 2NT that prefers 5-only-clubs to 4NT opposite no known support.  Your "open major"?  How does she know that you don't have it stopped?  You made a bid that said "if you have one more HCP than you have, we can make 12".  Without that point, now your hand won't cover 3 losers in that suit?  (ah, but you didn't actually do that.  And since you don't have that extra Q, just the two long diamonds, you "could see" the potential problem partner could have.  Notice, though, that partner can't see it!)
Whatever it showed, you are right you should correct to diamonds; partner will guess right.  To bring up yet more of my agreements, Meta-agreement #1: "Confusing bids are forcing" (that might apply to both partners here!)

I'm going to be obnoxious here, and pretend you're playing with my agreements with one of my partners.
First, this is definitely worth a slam invite.  The question you should ask is: Can you imagine many balanced 18 point hands opposite which slam is good?  The answer is yes - Axx xxx AQx AQxx makes 6N, and is only 16 points.  There are many variations.
Now - how do you either ask partner if they have a suitable hand or tell partner what a suitable hand would be?  The cards you're asking for are aces, the queen of diamonds, and the third diamond.  The queen of clubs is useful if partner does not have Axx(x) of hearts (or AK of spades).  The honors that are useless are the lower spade honors.
So I bid 3C, a transfer to diamonds, followed by 3S after partner's 3D bid.  The 3S bid shows slam interest and shortness in spades (telling partner that lower spade honors are useless).  If partner bids 3N, I make one more try with 4D, after which I'll pass partner's 4N or 5D bid.  If partner bids 4C (ace showing) or 4D (interest in slam), I bid 4H, which is keycard asking in diamonds.  If partner bids 4H, I bid 4S, showing one (or four, in theory) keycard.  If partner bids 5D, showing a terrible hand with no spade stopper, I pass.  If partner bids anything else, I bid 6D.
(These are hardly the most implausible agreements.  In fact, one bridge club in Seattle ran an individual a couple years ago with these as part of the imposed system.)

Here's my interpretation of my own bidding: "We've talked about clubs and diamonds, and I am promising 14 points opposite your presumed 18.. This would give us 32, making us odds on for 6NT, except that I'm worried that you have only Qxxx in one of the majors or Kxx in both,, causing us to lose the first two tricks. I only had 11 high card points, but my 7 diamonds should be worth two extra tricks (compared to five diamonds." I took five clubs to mean "I'm "open" in one of the majors, so let's play in my first-bd suit.

Slam bidding is not about counting points, but actually picturing how you will take 12 tricks.

I can count to 12 tricks with the two hands. Six diamonds, two clubs, three hearts, one spade. The only question is, can the defense win two tricks, say a diamond and the king of spades, before we get 12.

You're avoiding doing the right exercise.  1) figure out 5 different hands for partner (different in more than just low spot cards), consistent with their bidding so far, for which slam will likely make (against best defense).  2) figure out 5 different hands for partner for which slam will likely fail.  3) figure out a sequence of bids which will either give you the information to distinguish the first 5 hands from the second 5 hands, or a sequence of bids which will get a thinking partner to bid to slam on the first 5 hands and not on the second 5 hands.

Actually, I do an abbreviated version of this exercise. First, I make an inventory of outstanding honors (those not in my hand). Then I evaluate partner's bids, e.g. s/he opened and therefore has at least 12  points. Then I assign the best and worst possible configurations of partner's "12" points and see what I come up with. That's why "points" are so crucial to my analysis.

@TomAu: That's not "abbreviated", but rather "simplistic". Reason is that if you're not doing five distinct at each end you have no way to accurately estimate weighting between the two. Your method assumes that the arithmetic mean equals the median - which is frequently not the case when the distribution is uneven.
